# What is the best IDE on linux environment?

Tags: linux, ide

Is there an IDE such Visual Studio that helps the developer in linux env ?

Comment: You can try monodevelop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several, but it largely depends on what language you're planning to use.  For C++ you could try Qt Creator, for Java the obvious choice would be Eclipse.  Many other languages have Eclipse plugins available for them.

My personal favorite is Emacs, although that doesn't by itself count as an IDE.

Answer (score 2):

All OS developers write code in whatever editor they feel satisfied and feel easy to use(or they get used to their editors). Other than that, most operating systems are coded with custom Make scripts and don't use IDEs(unless you have modified the IDE to use a certain make script).

Its much easier to use what you know than to learn another tool to do the same just because the other guy next to me is using it and being productive.

Secondly: some OS developers I know code in VI/EMACS/NANO/gEDIT/MicroEMACS. Its a matter of taste. As long as you keep to the coding standards you're free to use whatever editor/ide you want.

Please see my answer here: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/169822/what-ides-or-editors-do-companies-like-google-apple-ibm-etc-use

Comment: i super quote this, especially the second paragraph "ts much easier to use what you know than to learn another tool to do the same just because the other guy next to me is using it and being productive."

Comment: @SamueleMattiuzzo hehe, just experience :)

Comment: that's the reason i super quoted you, "just experience" :D no IDE is better than the one you know best!

Comment: mine is just envy because you are able to do amazing things with just a few tools and I, with powerful tools such as aircraft carriers can do only mediocre things